# About $\frac{\partial^n f}{\partial x^n}$ ,for $f(x)$,What should I think, when $n[\in (\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q)^+]$ or $(\in \mathbb C)$?

Tags: derivatives

About $\frac{\partial^n f}{\partial x^n}$ ,for $f(x)$,What should I think, when $n[\in (\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q)^+]$ ,pozitive irrational? or  $(\in \mathbb C)$

For example;

$f(x)=x^2+3x\quad$  and $\quad n=\sqrt2\quad\to\quad \dfrac{\partial^{(\sqrt 2)} f}{\partial x^{(\sqrt2)}}=?$

and,

$f(x)=x^2+3x\quad$ and $\quad n=\sqrt i\quad\to\quad\dfrac{\partial^{(\sqrt i)} f}{\partial x^{(\sqrt i)}}=?$

And I think,I did grammar mistakes in the tittle, sorry about this.

Comment: Are you asking about how the *fractional derivative* is defined? If so, there are a few definitions given on the [*Fractional Calculus* page on *Wikipedia*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus)